# symfony2 - declare route another way

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I want to know if someone knows how to declare a `$router->get` route, but without symfony
using the expensive route compiler to compute the regex.

How to circumvent that whole ordeal.

What is the simplest way? adding a method to the router class that will directly populate the CompiledRoute?

Anybody done this already?

Comment: You can always just plugin in your own router class.  Be aware that the regex is cached so even if it is expensive to compute when building the cache, in a production environment it never needs to be rebuilt again unless your route definitions change.

Comment: @Cerad yes you are right, I just need something a little simpler without using the filesystem class, fileloader, etc. For demonstration purposes only. Would apc or memcache be a solution. I never used both of them.